# How can I recover my Terraria data?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I deleted Terraria so the local data would be deleted.

I tried re downloading the game but there was no old data that I played. Is it possible to get back? Will Copytrans Shellbee work?

My device is the iPad 4, running the iOS version of Terraria.

Comment: Have you tried actually contacting the game company?  How often do you back up your iPad?  You may be able to restore from your last backup to get your saved data.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to get your game data back would be if you had used
Gamecenter, which automatically saves your games to cloud. Unfortunately, if you didn't, there are no ways to get your data back.

Comment: This answer is correct...

Comment: @DatRoyce   Of course it is, _I_ made it.

Comment: Unless you have cloud save off...

Comment: It's certainly bold both to (a) claim that Gamecenter is the *only* way to have savegames persist, and (b) to imply it's right just because you wrote it! I'm not familiar with iOS backup apps, but is there any reason why Gamecenter would work rather than Copytrans Shelbee?

Comment: @GLaDOS - that italic i looks like a slash, looks like an emote.. `/madeit`

Comment: I saved it to my Game Center, I deleated because I said it is expired then I was thinking that I could update it, when I redownload terraria my.

Comment: Interesting. You must have deleted the cloud save too.